# Access to Message box buttons

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am having a message box a simple one inside an if condition and the thing is i want the message box to automatically close when the user points to the OK button in the message box, what i am not able to figure out is how to access the message box OK button

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Clipboard.Clear();

    //string queryvalue;
    //queryvalue = SelectedQuery.Value;
    //SelectedQuery.Value = queryvalue;
    if (QueryChooser.SelectedItem == null)
    {
        button3.Background = Brushes.PaleVioletRed;
        MessageBox.Show("Select a value");
    }
    else
    {
        Clipboard.SetText(SelectedQuery.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not clear the clipboard if you don't have a value to replace it with. Better put it right before Clipboard.SetText().

Answer (score 3):

In cases like this I've found that it is easier to just create a simple `Window` resembling a `MessageBox` and pop it using `ShowDialog()`, this way you'll have a more flexible "MessageBox".

Comment: Hmm true but i am trying to make a point to a friend that this can be done in programming as well.. so can it be done?

Comment: @JackyBoi, yes it can be done by using a low level mouse hook. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589468.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
if (MessageBox.Show("Select a value") == DialogResult.Ok) {
    // do something
}
```

UPDATE

As [Saeb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9722307/333404) already mentioned you should create your own simple `MessageBox` dialog.

Comment: No, he wants it so that if the user's mouse is over the OK button it automatically selects it, basically he wants to take over the behavior of the MessageBox.

Comment: Ah ok, I think I misunderstood the question.

Comment: This and the OP is using the Windows Forms version of MessageBox. I would recommend using the WPF version when in a WPF project. It is almost identical in syntax and lives in the System.Windows namespace.